# Prediction in Item-Item based collaborative filtering

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

I am creating an item-Based Collaborative Filtering Recommendation engine. I am trying to reduce the results of this paper: http://files.grouplens.org/papers/www10_sarwar.pdf.

I have a few questions and would greatly appreciate if someone would help me. In section 3.2.1 the predicted rating value is:

$$P_{u,i} = \dfrac{\sum_{\text{all similar items, N}}s_{i,N} * R_{u,N}}{\sum_{\text{all similar items, N}}(|s_{i,N}|)}.$$

Then in section 3.3 is says: For generating predictions for a user $u$ on item $i$, our algorithm first retrieves the precomputed $k$ most similar items corresponding to the target item $i$. Then it looks how many of those $k$ items were purchased by the user $u$, based on this intersection then the prediction is computed using basic item-based collaborative filtering algorithm.

My first question is:

1. What value is assigned to $P_{u, i}$ if the top $k$ items to item $i$ and the values for which ratings exist for user $u$ is empty?

In section 4.1 they say for the movielens data it is split for 80% training and 20% testing. The data set was converted into a user-item matrix with 943 rows and 1682 columns.

2. Do the authors split the data before converting to the user-item matrix or after?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can choose something that's impossible to achieve otherwise, such as  $P_{u,i} = -1$. Or if you have reason to believe that most of the values where there *are* overlapping preferences, will be reasonably far from 0, then you can set it to 0. Of course, what is *reasonably far* and *how many*, are all parts of the mysterious black-box called parameter tuning.
2. From the description in the paper, $943 \times 1682$ are the dimensions of the entire dataset, that is *before* they are split.